# How to replace cost of an item with the previous cost of the same item in a dataframe using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-preprocessing

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'O', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'O'], 'Item':['Apple','Banana','Carrot','Apple', 'Carrot', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'], 'Cost':[10, 12, 15, 13, 54, 20, 73, 22, 19, 32]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe
```

[image]

And I want to replace the cost of the current item with the cost of the previous item using Pandas, with the first instance of each item being deleted. So the above dataframe would become

```
data2 = {'ID': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'O'], 'Item':['Apple', 'Carrot', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'], 'Cost':[10, 15, 12, 13, 73, 20]}
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
dataframe2
```

[image]

What's a good way to do it?

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. Provide some more details to clarify and also `dataframe` as text not as image. May use `df.to_dict()`  and take a read on how to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on Item as well. This gives you output in the same order you expected

```
data['Cost'] = data.groupby('Item')['Cost'].shift(fill_value=0)
data[data['Cost'] != 0]
```

This gives us expected output:

```
  ID    Item  Cost
3  A   Apple    10
4  C  Carrot    15
6  B  Banana    12
7  A   Apple    13
8  B  Banana    73
9  O  Orange    20
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` and `head` with a negative number to exclude the last occurrence of each item:

```
>>> dataframe.groupby('Item').head(-1)
  ID    Item  Cost
0  A   Apple    10
1  B  Banana    12
2  C  Carrot    15
3  A   Apple    13
5  O  Orange    20
6  B  Banana    73
```